# Explain me this python expression in C#

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

What is the C# equivalent of this python expression?

```
file_no = int (last_file.Name.Replace(last_file.Extension,"")[-3:]);
```

I understand what `[-3:]` does but not the `(int)` cast.

Comment: [-3:] is a slice from the 3rd last character to the last character

Comment: @Senad http://diveintopython.org/native_data_types/lists.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing a value to the `int` constructor will attempt to turn it into a `int` (or `long`, if it is too big). Think [`Convert.ToInt32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for all who answerd. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 5):

It replaces the extension of a filename with the empty string, takes the last three characters as a string and tries to convert to an int.

So if `last_file` is `jamesbond007.secretagent` and `last_file.Extension` is `.secretagent` then `file_no` becomes `7` because `.secretagent` is replaced by the empty string, and the last three characters are `007` which is parsed into `7`.

```
int file_no = 
    Int32.Parse(
        last_file.Name.Replace(
            last_file.Extension, String.Empty
        )
        .Right(3)
    );
```

Comment: This is the better answer don't know why this has lower votes.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot tell you the answer in C#, but I can explain what this expression does: it takes the extension from a filename and then the last 3 characters and tries to convert these to int.

E.g. `measure009.bin -> measure009 -> 009 -> 9`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you say 'the int cast' I will assume you already know the value is being converted to an int. The reason is that before the cast the value is a string representation of an int and python will not let you use a 'string int' as an int.

oh, and it's python; you don't need to be obsessed with ';' line endings anynmore ;P

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a cast. `int` converts the argument into an integer, so the closest C# expression would be `int.Parse(...)` or a call using a converter.